# learning ado.net in c# and looking for good code sample

Tags: .net-3.5, ado.net, data-access-layer, sample

I am trying to learn ado.net. I want to see a real project, real code in 3 layes that works well and written well.
I underrstand every part  seperatly, I cn't get it right how it all work together
tthis why I am asking to download 3 layers winform/wpf solution
can anyone help?
thanks

Comment: Why not post the code you have that isn't working and then you can learn how to make each piece work.

Comment: do you mean examples of 3-Tier architecture, with a UI layer, Business layer and Data Access Layer?

Comment: Hi Lazarus- my code is working. the thing the project is a bit messy. I want to see how it should be written.

Russ-I mean 3 tier architecture. I want to see (in code) the connection between layers. like who opon the connection to the db? ect

Answer (score 1):

Good .net 3.5 layered application can be found [here (NerdDinner)](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/).  There are a bunch of tutorials videos around this.  Not sure how much use this may be for ADO.net, but it's a good way of structuring a data driven web app.

Comment: I downloaded it, can't open it yet in VS